# No XML at the location: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

Tags: android, xml

[image]

I press Alt + Enter and I click Fetch External Resource. It just gives me the error shown in the picture. I pressed Alt + Enter because when I put my cursor over the red text in the picture, it shows "Resource registered by this uri is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)"

I have tried Invalidating, Restarting, Opening and Closing the Project, Cleaning and Rebuilding, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you share your xml?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Android SDK installed?

Comment: You may put this question as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Android Studio `> File > Project Structure` :

  - **Location** >>> Ensure Android SDK location path is exists and correct

    - **MacOS** `/Users/{user}/Library/Android/sdk`
    - **Linux** `/home/{user}/Android/Sdk`
    - **Windows** `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk`
  - **Project**

    - **Android Plugin Repository** `jcenter, google()` // google optional when using google services